# Where is location of a log file of chromium on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: chromium, 19.10, log, logging

I can't found a chromium log file in default location, Where is it?
According to following page, default location is `~/.config/chromium` .
But there is no log file in this directory.
[Chromium User Data Directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md#Linux)

https://superuser.com/questions/1286937/how-can-i-find-my-browser-web-log-file

I using selenium webdriver from Python to scrape information from websites.
It has caused errors in chromium, so I need to get log.
Then I added [flags to enable logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging), but the log file isn't in the directory.

```
options.add_argument("--enable-logging")
options.add_argument("--log-level=0")
```

I suppose that chromium has changed to snap package since 19.10, Maybe it seems like causes move of default directory. (I can't find it, I have no idea actually).

I would like to see contents of browser console and output it to file.

Where is the location of chromium log file in Ubuntu 19.10?

### Update1:

I tried `sudo find / -name "chrome*.log"`, it result is "not found".
It means that the log file does not exists.
Are there wrong points in passed options?

End of update1

---

## Update 2:

I tried another options like following, it works for output chromium log to stderr, but does not output to log file. (I can't found chrome_debug.log in ~/.config/chromium)

```
options.add_argument("--enable-logging")
options.add_argument("--v=1")
```

Comment: Have you done a global search through the entire filesystem for _chrome_debug.log_ e.g.,  _sudo find / -name chrom*.log_? After you've done that, please click [edit] and put the result into the question.

Comment: Oh I forgot that I will try it!

Comment: I have updated: There is no the log file.

Comment: Please go to Chromium's home directory and, from a command line, do: 
"./chrome  --enable-logging=stderr --v=1" 
and use it for a minute, then close the app. Is there a logfile now?

Comment: So this is a snap in 19.10. You may need to look somewhere else other than $HOME/.config/. Maybe there's a snap-something somewhere?

Comment: @K7AAY I got a log!, but it does not fill content of log to ~/.config/chrome_debug.log, Is there any way to output to specific file?
Note that I using it through python selenium binding so I want to get it as a file.